# Difference between job is done, job has done and job has been done?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

it's my first post here. So sorry for mistakes.
Today I watched instastory and I saw christmass tree with writing: "job is done". I thought about it and different between:

- It is done (-- I don't know it's right )
- It has done (-- It's Present Perfect )
- It has been done

Can someone explain me difference?

Comment: "Job is done" looks like an example of **headlinese**, which is a kind of simplified grammar we often use for headlines and signs.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence **'it is done'** is *present simple passive voice*. With a help of *passive voice* you can inform someone that **someone did/finished the job**. Or something is done by somebody regularly/everyday/as expected...

> The room is cleaned by Tom.
> (Tom cleaned the room).

When it comes to your second sentence saying **job has done**
It is *present perfect active voice*. Now it might mean that 'job' finished something or did something. So let's replace it with *Tom*.

> **Tom has done** the job. (Tom finished it).

As for your third sentence, it is *present perfect passive voice*
You can use it to tell that something has been done by someone at some time up to now.

> Active : Thomas has written many books.
> Passive: Many books have been written by Thomas.